# AdapterView.OnItemClickListener

Tags: android

In methods like these kind,

`onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)`,

what's the difference between `position` and `id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the `id` is, as the name suggests, an identifier, that you can use to identify that specific item in the adapter. `Position` refers to the index of the item, in the adapter.

Comment: In particular, the id will be the _ID column from the Cursor, if you are using some flavor of CursorAdapter.

Comment: Ah! now i see what the 'id' is for,its the identifier for the data item in the adapter

Answer (score 0):

`position` is the position of the view in the adapter, while `id` is the row id of the item selected.